# Как перенести строки в notepad++

Tags: notepad++

подскажите пожалуйста, есть нотепад++ и в нем открыто два документа, один из документов содержит много емайлов, каждый с новой строки. Мне нужно перенести некоторые из них выборочно во второй пустой документ. Я настроил нотепад так, что бы я мог выделять каждый емайл через ctrl, затем следующий и так сколько хочешь, что бы не перекидывать по одному потому что это слишком долго. Но возникла проблема, когда я вставляю их в новый документ, они вставляются не в каждой строке, а все вместе кучей. Как предложением. Что мне нужно сделать что бы они вставлялись отдельно в новой строке? Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно выделить не только нужную строку, но и начало следующей (без символов). Тогда вы скопируете перенос строки

Comment: Вы немного не поняли, мне нужно скопировать много строк, но все они в разных местах.

Comment: Называется множественный перенос, только вставляется сплошным текстом...